# How to solve "Argument type 'CustomStruct' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'"

Tags: swift, xcode

I was trying to use the codes below to *shuffle* an array consisted of a simple custom struct called `Card`, and I get an error at `cards.remove(at: randomIndex)`:

```
Error: Argument type 'Card' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'
```

Here are the codes:

```
var cards = [Card]()  // declare the array
var shuffledCards = [Card]()
for _ in cards.indices {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count)))
    shuffledCards += cards.remove(at: randomIndex)  // error appears here
}
cards = shuffledCards
```

Oddly, as a contrast, the similar design works for `Array<String>`:

```
var emojiChoices = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(emojiChoices.count)))
emoji[card.identifier] = emojiChoices.remove(at: randomIndex)
```

Should I add something the the definition of `Card`? If so, what should I add? Thanks!

Comment: I am using Xcode 9, which ships with Swift 4.

Comment: Can you show your Card declaration please ?

Comment: @OhadM `Card` is currently empty. It seems something else caused the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+=` operator in

```
shuffledCards += cards.remove(at: randomIndex)
```

expects a *sequence* of elements which should be append to the 
`shuffledCards` array (for example another array). To append a single element, use

```
shuffledCards.append(cards.remove(at: randomIndex))
```

Comment: Oh yeah! It works! Thanks! Really appreciate the explanation on  the mechanism of `+=`!